# react-bootstrap-table: insertModalBody not working for me

Tags: react-bootstrap-table

My codes (following the [example](https://gist.github.com/AllenFang/bb06cc4740762bfea8ac50c2d620cbb1#file-custom-insert-modal-body-jsx-L62)):

```
class MyCustomBody extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<form>
      <div className="form-group"><label>Email</label><input type="text" placeholder="Email" className="form-control editor edit-text"></input></div>
      <div className="form-group"><label>Role</label><select placeholder="Role" className="form-control editor edit-select"><option value="Admin">Admin</option><option value="Client">Client</option></select></div>
      <div className="form-group"><label>Name</label><input type="text" placeholder="Name" className="form-control editor edit-text"></input></div>
      <div className="form-group"><label>Password</label><input type="text" placeholder="Password" className="form-control editor edit-text"></input></div>
    </form>);
  }
}

class MyDashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.createCustomModalBody = this.createCustomModalBody.bind(this);
  }

  createCustomModalBody() {
    return <MyCustomBody/>;
  }

  render() {

    const options = {
      insertModalBody: this.createCustomModalBody
    };

    return (
      <BootstrapTable data={(this.props.users || [])}
        options={options}
        insertRow
        search >
        <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='_id'>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='email'>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='role'>Role</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='profile' dataFormat={this.nameFormatter}>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='password' hidden>Password</TableHeaderColumn>
      </BootstrapTable>
    );
  }
}
```

Some codes removed. When `+new` button clicked, the default form shown instead of my customized form. Any ideas? Thanks